# Possible to have wheel and controller connected at the same time on xbox?

Tags: controllers, forza-motorsport-7

I'm trying to play Forza Motorsport 7 with a Thrustmaster wheel and have the xbox controller connected at the same time to navigate the menus and also use the headphone jack that comes built into it. But as it is, whenever I have the controller connected the wheel won't do anything to the car. As soon as I turn the controller off, the wheel works immediately.

Can't I have both on (and assigned to the same player)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the solution was simple and a matter of turn order:
- Turn the xbox controller off and when it says connect controller hit the wheel button, then you can turn controller back on.

Answer (score 0):

I used to play Forza Horizon 3 on Windows using a G27, and there I was only able to have one input device at a time, that you had to set in the options menu. I assume that you have to change which device is the main input device when you want to switch, which I understand may not be as simple as it sounds since you are also using the audio output from the controller.